# Conditional Order by clause in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have read some posts having the same problem. I tried to adapt their answers but not succeeded.
I want to sort columns by status than as per status further sort the columns.
May the below query will clear my point

```
SELECT a.*,STR_TO_DATE(d_date, "%m/%d/%Y")>CURDATE() as status
FROM table AS a ORDER BY status DESC, 
IF(status=0,
'DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE( a.d_date, "%m/%d/%Y" ),CURDATE()) DESC',
'DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE( a.d_date, "%m/%d/%Y" ),CURDATE()) ASC')
```

UPDATE:
After below query

```
SELECT a . * , STR_TO_DATE( d_date,  "%m/%d/%Y" ) > CURDATE( ) AS 
STATUS 
FROM  `table` AS a
ORDER BY STATUS DESC , IF( 
STATUS =0, DATEDIFF( STR_TO_DATE( a.d_date,  "%m/%d/%Y" ) , CURDATE( ) ) DESC , DATEDIFF( STR_TO_DATE( a.d_date, "%m/%d/%Y" ) , CURDATE( ) ) ASC ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I've got the below error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC, DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE( a.d_date, "%m/%d/%Y" ),CURDATE()) ASC) LIMIT ' at line 4
```

If my table name is `table` than For this recored

```
d_date
06/28/2012
06/23/2012
06/20/2012
06/19/2012
```

if current date is `06/21/2012`

the output should be

```
d_date               status
06/23/2012              1
06/28/2012              1
06/20/2012              0
06/19/2012              0
```

May this information is enough. Please let me know if it's not clear yet.

Thanks

Comment: Do not use quotation marks in your `IF` ... else it will be considered as a string.

Comment: is `IF` supported in mysql or not.Iam doubtful

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble : its allowed. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if-statement.html)

Comment: @arnep:when I tried it without quotes there is #1064 error

Comment: Can you try solutions below. Or post complete errors?

Comment: @Irfan : Can you provide sample output? I don't get what you are trying to do? Based on status define the order is something ODD for me...

Comment: @Irfan : Your example made it easy for Devart.. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  STR_TO_DATE(d_date, '%m/%d/%Y') > CURDATE() AS status
FROM
  table AS a
ORDER BY
  status DESC, 
  IF(status = 0,
    DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(a.d_date, '%m/%d/%Y'),CURDATE()) * -1,
    DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(a.d_date, '%m/%d/%Y'),CURDATE())
  )
```

Comment: Thanks Devart your answer did the job.

Comment: Yes, it is a small trick that helps to avoid using ASC or DESC in the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this (new) solution will do the trick:

```
SELECT a.*, STR_TO_DATE(d_date, "%m/%d/%Y")>CURDATE() as status 
FROM `table` AS a ORDER BY status DESC, 
IF(status=0,
CONCAT_WS(' ', DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE( a.d_date, "%m/%d/%Y" ),CURDATE()), 'DESC'),
CONCAT_WS(' ', DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE( a.d_date, "%m/%d/%Y" ),CURDATE()), 'ASC'))
```